# fbconnect api on android emulator (Java)

Tags: android, facebook, android-emulator, fbconnect

Hi there I am quite new to eclipse and the android emulator.

I am trying to connect to facebook in my app. I have downloaded and installed all the correct SDK's and the fbconnect API and using the tutorial from http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/845/ i have managaed to import and debug the project. I've dealt with all the build path errors and so on...

the problem the I am having now is that when I run the android project, the emulator loads and comes up but i get the following message "Application messaging (in process com.android.mms) is not responding".

i then tried to run it from the android emulator and i get the following error message " the application FB connect (process test.One) has stopped unexpectedly please try again".
i have also tried running the app on various android versions, from version 1.6 to 2.2 and still no luck!

Any suggestions as to how to fix this problem will be very helpful as i am all out of ideas.

thank you.

Comment: paste the error from logcat...

Comment: LogCat error message:
02-28 12:33:33.908: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(217): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.One/test.One.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBLoginButton

Comment: And is the class com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBLoginButton actually present in your project? It needs to be...

Comment: Yeah the project includes the FBLoginButton

Comment: i have checked all the paths of each class and they should all be working fine now, but i still get the same force to close message with the android emulator!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey I figured it out!! :) lol

well basically with the help of the LogCat tool I went through all the errrors that were coming up and realised that I had 2 AndroidManifest XML files sitting in my project (due to continuous importing), and one of those Manifest files had an incorrect package path, so I just deleted it and used the other :) this worked fine and for the first time ever the emulator did NOT show any "force to close errors"!

hope this helps anyone who makes the same mistake (even though it was a quite a blonde one, but we all live and learn). lol

thanks for all the input guys and girls.